# Augustine, De Civitate Dei, Book XVII, Ch. XVI

Tags: translation-check, latin-to-english-translation, augustinus

In *De Civitate Dei*, Augustine of Hippo wrote,<sup>1</sup>

> *Quis non hic Christum, quem praedicamus et in quem credimus, quamlibet sit tardus, agnoscat, **cum audiat Deum**, cuius sedes est in saecula saeculorum, et unctum a Deo, utique sicut unguit Deus, non visibili, sed spiritali atque intellegibili chrismate? Quis enim tam rudis est in hac religione vel tam surdus adversus eius famam longe lateque diffusam, ut Christum a chrismate, hoc est ab unctione appellatum esse non noverit?*

which I translate as,

> Who here, however slow he may be, does not recognize Christ whom we preach, and in whom we believe, **when he hears [that he is] God**, whose throne is for ever and ever, and [he is] anointed by God, as God indeed anoints, not with a visible, but with a spiritual and even intelligible chrism (chrismate)? For who is so ignorant in this religion, or so deaf to its far and wide-spread fame, that he has not known that Christ (*Christum*) is named from chrism (*chrismate*), this is, from anointing?

My question concerns the phrase *cum audiat Deum*. I recognize this to be the preposition *cum* followed by a verb conjugated in the subjunctive mood, active voice, 3rd person, singular number, from the lemma *audio*, followed by a noun declined in the accusative case. Because I do not believe this should be translated as “when he hears God” (before researching Lewis & Short, my initial translation was “when he hears [that he is] God”), I reviewed Lewis & Short’s entry for the verb *audio* and noted the following:

> D. To hear thus and thus, i. e. **to be named** or styled somehow (as in Gr. ἀκούω; and in Engl. to hear, as Milton: Or hear'st thou rather pure ethereal stream, P. L. III. 7); and with bene or male (as in Gr. καλῶς or κακῶς ἀκούειν; cf. Milton: For which Britain hears ill abroad, Areop.; and Spenser: If old Aveugles sonnes so evil hear, F. Q. I. 5, 23), to be in good or bad repute, to be praised or blamed, to have a good or bad character: “benedictis si certāsset, audīsset bene (Bene audire est bene dici, laudari, Don.),” Ter. Phorm. prol. 20: “tu recte vivis, si curas esse quod audis,” Hor. Ep. 1, 16, 17: “rexque paterque Audisti coram,” id. ib. 1, 7, 38; so id. S. 2, 6, 20; Ter. Hec. 4, 2, 24; id. Phorm. 2, 3, 12; Cic. Att. 6, 1; id. Fin. 3, 17, 57; id. Leg. 1, 19; Nep. Dion, 7, 3: “Ille, qui jejunus a quibusdam et aridus habetur, non aliter ab ipsis inimicis male audire quam nimiis floribus et ingenii afluentia potuit,” Quint. 12, 10, 13 al.—In a play upon words: erat surdaster M. Crassus; “sed aliud molestius quod male audiebat,” Cic. Tusc. 5, 40, 116; so, “minus commode: quod illorum culpā se minus commode audire arbitrarentur,” Cic. Verr. 2, 3, 58.—

Could *cum audiat Deum* be translated as “when he is named ‘God’”?

---

### References

Sancti Aurelii Augustini Episcopi. [*De Civitate Dei, Libri XXII.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=mjgMkMoNWJoC) Vol. 2. Lipsiae: Teubneri, 1877.

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> *De Civitate Dei* (“On the City of God”), Book 17, Ch. 16, p. [238](https://books.google.com/books?id=mjgMkMoNWJoC&pg=PA238#v=onepage&q&f=true)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you may be overthinking this a bit: this particular meaning of *audire* is idiomatic, but derives pretty directly from the base meaning. I think the bolding of the L&S entry gives somewhat the wrong idea of the construction, as if one could say: "Audio Brianus" = "*I am named Brian.*"

By far the most common usage of this idiom is with an adverb, particularly *bene* and *male*:

> Ab inimicis male audio.
>
> *I have a bad reputation among my enemies.* (Lit: *I hear badly from my enemies.*)

The examples given in Lewis and Short very rarely cite a usage without an adverb. Here are two I found, though:

> tu recte vivis, si curas esse quod audis. (Hor. Ep. 1:16)
>
> *You live uprightly, if you take care to be what others say of you.* (Lit: *...be what you hear.*)

Note, however, that this meaning is so established that it can be used with the *nominative*:

> Saepe uerecundum laudasti rexque paterque
>   audisti coram nec uerbo parcius absens; (Hor. Ep. 1:7)
>
> *You have often praised me as modest, and you have heard me
>
>   call you king and father in your presence, nor am I more sparing in my words in your absence.*
>   (Lit: *You have heard king and father*)

Two notes:

1. The subject of the *audio* is the one who is "regarded as X"
2. In the case of a noun, nominative is (*probably*) more appropriate.

Now let's look at your example sentence, which I will pare down to its essential structure:

> Quis Christum non agnoscat, cum audiat Deum?

There are two reasons, based on the above two observations, why I believe your proposed translation will not work:

1. ***Deus* should probably be nominative.**
2. More important: **the subject of *audiat* would be *Christus*, which does not make sense.** Obviously, the *quis* who *agnoscat* is not God, so we have to assume that the subject becomes *Christus*. All of a sudden, *cum* is not restrictive but *explanatory* (pardon the non-technical terms). The translation becomes:

> Who does not acknowledge Christ, since [Christ] is known as God?

Augustine's point is obviously dependent on the subject of the first clause (*quis*) hearing something. Using Ockham's razor and the above observations, it is much simpler to supply an (often excised) *esse* and translate as:

> Quis Christum non agnoscat, cum audiat [eum esse] Deum.